# User input validation not validating correctly, any suggestions for what I may be doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, while-loop

I'm trying to validate user's input with a while loop so that only integers and number's greater than 8 are accepted. The code I have currently runs properly when a string is inputed and prints the correct output.

However, the problem I am running into is that when a user enters a integer less than 8 it displays the "Incorrect Input" message that I want, but when it prompts the user to enter another input. When I re-enter a integer greater than 8 it still prints "Incorrect Input" when I want it to break to the next prompt. Anyone have suggestions that I may be doing wrong? I'm not allowed to define a function for this particular assignment.

```
Number_List = []

while (True):
    try:
        Number_List.extend(map(int, input("Enter the length, width, and height of the room: ").split()))
    except ValueError:
        print("\nIncorrect Input. \nPlease try again. \n")
        continue

    if (Number_List[0] < 8) or (Number_List[1] < 8) or (Number_List[2] < 8):
        print("\nIncorrect Input. \nPlease try again. \n")
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are extending your list. So when you enter new inputs, the numbers are added at the end of `Number_List`.

Therefore `Number_List[0]`, `Number_List[1]`, `Number_List[2]` always stay the same.

To understand better, I advise you to print `Number_List` before the except.

To make it works you could simply replace the corresponding line to:

```
Number_List = list((map(int, input("Enter the length, width, and height of the room: ").split())))
```

With that you will create a new list every time.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be able to provide an answer. Just to share my observation by pasting your code to python tutor.

So first of all, your original goal was to:
**validate user's input with a while loop so that only integers and number's greater than 8 are accepted**

I did some experiment of your code by trying different input combo.

- case 1: input ➡️ 10 8 9

  the code works just fine.
- case 2: I'm attempting to add a number less than 8 to trigger 'ValueError'
  input ➡️ 8 **6** 14

then it did trigger, 'Incorrect Input.
Please try again.'showed up, no problem with that, and then input box showed up suggesting to enter new set of inputs.

Now, here's the problem: the list you created 'Number_List = []' still have those incorrect input, so even though you enter new input, the list would just keep growing bigger and bigger, **without any sort of cleanup mechanism**, the incorrect input will still inside the list.

Hopes that would inspire you to fix the code. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue with my program. Cheers!

Comment: @thai_green_curry  Another way to solve this is to carefully consider where you are going to place Number_List = [], this is an empty list, isn't it? right now, its location is outside the while loop, which makes it kept storing inputs without any sort of cleanup mechanism, however, if you place it under 'while(True):'
every time it run the while loop, it will clean up its input to refresh it to become a empty list again.

Comment: I didn't know that! Thank you for the clarification, that would have made things much easier. I will definitely keep that in mind next time I make a while loop. I appreciate the advice.